# Trying to log to Windows Azure Diagnostics log from Enterprise Library 6.0

Tags: azure, enterprise-library, azure-diagnostics

I am trying to log exceptions to `WADLogsTable` on Windows Azure. "Rolling Flat File" listener works but when I add this listener it does not work:

```
<loggingConfiguration name ="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="WADX">
      </add>
    </listeners>
... more configuration details
</loggingConfiguration>
```

The exception I keep getting is:

`Missing TraceListenerData type in configuration 'name="WADX"'`

There are no inner exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the listenerDataType attribute. The following example works for us albeit using Enterprise Library 5.

```
  <add listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.SystemDiagnosticsTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
       type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
       name="LogListener" />
```

Comment: That's precisely what I was missing, though I found it before I saw the answer. :-) Thanks, accepted it as a correct answer

Comment: Had same issue, but unfortunately couldn't find Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics assembly in the latest Azure SDK (2.9.5), or a working copy in unofficial Nuget sources. It looks like a dependency is missing, and I couldn't find the correct versions in Nuget. Has DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener moved to another assembly?